# Self service kiosk for cell phone and other device battery charging on the go

Tags: batteries, charging, cellphone

We have a micro business in the form of self-service cell phone charging stations that we place in busy areas and people pay a small fee to use. Our question is, with all the new and always improving phones on the market, is there an amperage output and a voltage output "level" that we could provide via the stations that will cater for most phones, even the current smartphones like Blackberry Z10 etc for example? Tablets?

Answer (score 2):

There is not a standard for the current set resistors that connect to the D+ & D- pins on the USB cable.  You are going to have to research the resistor / voltage values on those pins for each of the different smartphone and tablet models that you want to support.

The power supply is pretty standard.  Most chargers now will supply somewhere around 2 Amps @ 5 Vdc.  But the device uses the resistors and/or voltage levels on the D+ & D- pins to set the appropriate charge current.

Because you want your customer to receive the maximum charge current possible, you need to tailor the resistors and voltages on those pins to match their devices.  This might be as simple as having a selector switch for each of your charging ports and allow the customer to select which device he / she has.

Your station might be as simple as having several desktop PC power supplies in the enclosure.  The 5 Vdc output from each power supply can feed a dozen or more charging ports.  You will want to have over-current protection for each port - this might be as simple as using a self-resetting fuse (polyswitch) at each port.

You would also have your device selector for each port.  This might be as simple as having a 6 position, 2 pole rotary switch.

I don't believe there is any danger in selecting the wrong resistors / voltages on the USB connector D+ & D- lines.  The worst that should happen is that the device will fall back to the 100 mA current value that is available from any USB port.

One added touch might be to have a current meter at each port.  Then let the customer select the best switch position for the maximum current possible.

Comment: +1 for the current meter. Inline USB current meters are available inexpensively.